# Multiple video players in viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-mediaplayer

I want to play videos on different fragments in viewpager. I use multiple mediaplayers and surfaceviews for each fragment. When I swipe left or right, I want to pause and start videos as well. Swipe to next video has no problem at all but when i swipe to previous video(that is already playing) surfaceviews overlap. Meanwhile, I can play and pause videos without problem.

I tried almost all possible combinations of setZorderMedia and setZOrderonTop but I failed.

In short, the problem is that surfaceviews overlap in viewpager. Here are the problem related codes, layouts and a screenshot of the problem.

Layout of the activity that contains viewpager

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_tweet_activity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".TweetActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager_tweet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_avatar"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="80dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_avatar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_avatar"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="7pt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_tweet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image_avatar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_avatar"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="7pt" />

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/video_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_tweet" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoSurfaceContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/videoSurface"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment.class

```
    private Context context=getActivity();
private View rootView;
private Typeface type;

private SurfaceView videoSurface; 
private MediaPlayer player; 
private VideoControllerView controller;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tweet, container, false);
    context=getActivity();

    videoSurface = (SurfaceView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);      
    //videoSurface.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);
    //videoSurface.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    SurfaceHolder videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder(); 
    videoHolder.addCallback(this);

    player = new MediaPlayer(); 
    controller = new VideoControllerView(context);


    RelativeLayout videoView=(RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_container);

    videoView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            controller.show(); 
            return false;
        }           
    });


    try {
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rootView;
}

// Implement SurfaceHolder.Callback
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    player.setDisplay(holder);
    player.prepareAsync();
    isSurfaceCreated=true;

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    player.release();
}
// End SurfaceHolder.Callback

// Implement MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
    //player.start();
}
// End MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener

// Implement VideoMediaController.MediaPlayerControl
@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return player.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return player.getDuration();
}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return player.isPlaying();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    player.pause();
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int i) {
    player.seekTo(i);
}

@Override
public void start() {
    player.start();
}

@Override
public boolean isFullScreen() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void toggleFullScreen() {
}
// End VideoMediaController.MediaPlayerControl
```

[My VideoControllerView](https://github.com/yasinalm/ExampleMediaController/blob/master/src/uk/co/brightec/example/mediacontroller/VideoControllerView.java)

My activity that contains viewpager (again the problem related part in onCreate method of the activity)

```
currentFragment=pager.getCurrentItem();
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int index) {

            TweetFragment current=pagerAdapter.getItem(currentFragment);
            current.pause();

            TweetFragment selected=pagerAdapter.getItem(index);
            selected.start();

            currentFragment=index;
        }
    });
```

Swipe to next video has no problem; [image: Image 1]

Swipe back to a video that is paused before;
[image: Image 2]

If there is anymore necessary information, please ask.

Comment: I would suggest you to study feasibility of playing multiple videos on different phones first. Because not all the phone have hardware capability to support multiple video play.

Comment: Thanks for comment but that is not my primary concern.

Comment: If you are ok to pause and restart the video as you swipe then couldn't you just get away with a single surface view (the currently playing video).  Then on swipe start pause the video, replace it with a static thumbnail, proceed with the view swipe, swipe in a new static thumbnail,replace the surfaceview with the new video, start play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are using a SurfaceView for your video.

Try using a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) instead.

From documentation:

> Unlike SurfaceView, TextureView does not create a separate window but behaves as a regular View. This key difference allows a TextureView to be moved, transformed, animated, etc.

*Edit*

I don't know why the negative vote, a `SurfaceView` will create a new window to draw its content. 
(This is an independent window from the window of the activity, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) ).

Also note that the zOrder calls need to be called before the surface view's containing window is attached to the window manager so you cant rearrange the zOrder of your `SurfaceViews` after they are created and attached.

If you really want to use multiple `SurfaceViews` at the same time you could try calling `setVisibility (int visibility)` on your `SurfaceView` when you switch pages.

Make your `videoSurface` variable public and call `current.setVisibility(View.GONE)` after `current.pause()` and `current.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` after `current.start()` .

I'm not sure if that will work though..

Your best bet would be to either create/destroy the `SurfaceViews` each time you change a page, or try using a `TextureView` as I mentioned before.